# Custom service contract attribute

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm looking to implement something similar to the way JSONP callbacks work with WCF in .NET 4. If you pass a callback parameter it wraps the response without callback needing to be in your method signature. What I want to do is have an attribute that switches the response format if a parameter named format is passed. I want it to not require the format parameter in the method signature.

Anyone have a starting point suggestion, doubts of possibility, tips?

Comment: The fact that JSONP is wrapped is because it won't work otherwise; in principle, it's hack to work around a cross-domain issue. On any case, I'm wondering why you want something similar. Pls tell a little bit about the application you are working on.

Comment: I continually find myself adding a format parameter and switching between default XML response and JSON/JSONP if requested. I use a central service shared across apps which is why cross domain, not a concern for server side but ill gladly use jsonp to get around client side limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a couple of components to implement the response wrapping. JSONP support was added to WCF on .NET Framework 4.0, before that there was a sample which showed how it can be implemented, so you can look at that to see what you need to do. You can find the sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898.aspx.